# Camera freezing when using FlareNFT with FLARManager

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, augmented-reality, flare, flartoolkit

I'm trying to run the example application from the [FlarManager](http://words.transmote.com/wp/flarmanager/) download. It worked first time using the FlarToolkit engine, but the webcam freezes if I change to the [FlareNFT](http://www.imagination.at/en/?Products%3aAugmented_Reality_for_Flash%3aflare%2anft) tracker. The only change I've made is to the onAdded function:

From this:

```
this.flarManager = new FLARManager("../resources/flar/flarConfig.xml", new FlarToolkitManager(), this.stage);
```

To this:

```
this.flarManager = new FLARManager("../resources/flar/flarConfig.xml", new FlareNFTManager(), this.stage);
```

When using the FlareNFTManager it compiles but freezes the camera feed. No errors are thrown, but the FlarManager event handlers are not triggered (e.g. onFlarManagerInited, onMarkerAdded, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

you have to make sure that the flare settings in the flarConfig.xml file are correct (i.e. check that all listed file are in place):

```
<trackerSettings>
        <flareSettings
            resourcesPath="../resources/flare/"
            cameraParamsFile="cam.ini">
            <nftSettings
                featureSetFile="featureSet.ini"
                framerate="30"
                multiTargets="false" />
        </flareSettings>
```

...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, and resolved it by putting the .lic file in placein the bin-debug folder when compiling the app. On a side note though - do you know how to create markers that flarNFT will recognize?

Comment: FlareNFT is a proprietary product so you need to send them the images you want to use and they convert them to pattern files. The licence is a little expensive, but if you were using AR for any commercial projects you'd need to pay for the original AR library anyway so it's not a great deal more on top of that.